# TypeError when using createAWSConnection from @acuris/aws-es-connection

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am trying to set up a connection to AWS Elasticsearch using the @acuris/aws-es-connection library. I am executing this on an active AWS instance, but I'm encountering an issue when calling the createAWSConnection function.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import { 
    createAWSConnection, 
    awsGetCredentials 
} from '@acuris/aws-es-connection';

async function setupConnection() {
    const awsCredentials = await awsGetCredentials();
    const clientOptions = createAWSConnection(awsCredentials);
    // rest of the connection setup...
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

`TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null at generateAWSConnectionClass...`

I have confirmed that the AWS SDK is installed and properly configured. Both the Elasticsearch JS client (@elastic/elasticsearch) and the @acuris/aws-es-connection libraries are also installed with the latest version.

Is anyone familiar with this issue or can provide guidance on how to debug and resolve it?

Comment: did you resolve this issue? If yes then can you paste the resolution so that it help others.

Comment: @node_saini was not able to, had to approach the problem differently in the end